# Elisp: boundp in let

Tags: emacs, elisp, let

How can I check a variable is defined before or not within the let construct?

```
 (let (((if (boundp 'a)
           'a
         'dummy) t))
   (message "I made this work"))
```

What I am trying to do is to check whether or not `a` is bounded before, if it is already, bind it to `t` locally. otherwise don't care about `a` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code fails with: `(wrong-type-argument symbolp (if (boundp (quote a)) (quote a) (quote dummy)))`, indicating that the `let` special form* does not evaluate that argument (although that list would evaluate to a symbol, the list *itself* is not a symbol).

Here's a simple-but-flawed alternative approach which creates a local binding for `a` regardless, but then unbinds it in that local scope if it was unbound originally.

```el
(let ((a (if (boundp 'a) t nil)))
  (or a (makunbound 'a))
  ;; do things
  )
```

The flaw is that if `a` was initially unbound, you would want an assignment to `a` within that local scope to outlive the local scope, and it won't with this approach.

Initially I was thinking you'd need to forego `let` entirely to get around that issue, and just use something like this:

```el
(when (boundp 'a)
  (setq a-backup a
        a t))
;; do things
(when (boundp 'a-backup)
  (setq a a-backup)
  (makunbound 'a-backup))
```

Then I realised that, as with so many things, macros are the answer:

```el
(defmacro let-if-bound (var value &rest body)
  "Bind variable VAR to VALUE only if VAR is already bound."
  (declare (indent 2))
  `(if (boundp ',var)
       (let ((,var ,value))
         ,@body)
     (progn ,@body)))

(let-if-bound a t
  ;; do things
  )
```

> (*) A "special form" is a primitive function specially marked so that its
>   arguments are not all evaluated.  Most special forms define control
>   structures or perform variable bindings--things which functions cannot
>   do.
>
> Each special form has its own rules for which arguments are evaluated
>   and which are used without evaluation.  Whether a particular argument is
>   evaluated may depend on the results of evaluating other arguments.

Comment: @phills First of all Thanks for answering. I understand the limitation of let construct. I also thought the work around you mentioned. I just didn't like the coupling binding and unbinding same expression.

Comment: edited the question to fix parenthesis. I will wait some more time before accepting.

Comment: @phils The macro solution as defined will not be dynamic if the code is compiled.  You should fix it.

Comment: event_jr: Thanks; I'll be happy to fix it, but I'm afraid I'm unsure of the problem (and unable to cause any when testing). Could you elaborate on the circumstances in which the code won't work?

Comment: @phils `(if (boundp var` is a part of the macro, not the form that the macro emits.  This means that form emitted by the macro will depend on the value of `var` at compilation time, not at run time.

Comment: event_jr: Aha; thank you very much. Fixed (and committed to memory)!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "canonical" way to do that would be

```
(let ((bound (boundp 'a))
      (a t))
  (unless bound (makunbound 'a))
  ...blabla...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer., Infact I ended up using exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, that's a little nicer than my version of the same. It comes with the same caveat that *assignments* to `a` within that scope will not survive that scope's exit in either case, so whether you'd use this approach or a macro depends on your level of 'not caring' about `a` if it wasn't previously bound.